# Show directive one at a time AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to use multiple directive in one page such that only one datepicker should be enable at one time, I tried by adding dynamic class but somehow I need to double click in input box to hide another. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcJr9zg9PeUeRX4kRhbW?p=preview

**HTML Code -**

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl"> 
    <div class="" ng-repeat="row in fakeDataSet" style="height: 150px; float: left;">
        <my-datepicker 
            dateid="dateid"
            first-week-day-sunday="true" 
            placeholder="Choose date"
            view-format="Do MMMM YYYY"
            checkval="$index">
        </my-datepicker>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS Code -**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.fakeDataSet = [34,787,56,78];
})

myApp.directive('myDatepicker', ['$document', function($document) {

    'use strict';

    var setScopeValues = function (scope, attrs) {
        scope.format = attrs.format || 'YYYY-MM-DD';
        scope.viewFormat = attrs.viewFormat || 'Do MMMM YYYY';
        scope.locale = attrs.locale || 'en';
        scope.firstWeekDaySunday = scope.$eval(attrs.firstWeekDaySunday) || false; 
        scope.placeholder = attrs.placeholder || '';
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            checkval: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {           
            scope.dynamicMyDatePicker = 'my-datepicker' + "_" + scope.checkval, 
            scope.dynamicMyDatePickerInput = 'my-datepicker-input' + "_" + scope.checkval;

            setScopeValues(scope, attrs);

            scope.calendarOpened = false;
            scope.days = [];
            scope.dayNames = [];
            scope.viewValue = null;
            scope.dateValue = null;

            moment.locale(scope.locale);
            var date = moment();

            var generateCalendar = function (date) {
                var lastDayOfMonth = date.endOf('month').date(),
                    month = date.month(),
                    year = date.year(),
                    n = 1;

                var firstWeekDay = scope.firstWeekDaySunday === true ? date.set('date', 2).day() : date.set('date', 1).day();
                if (firstWeekDay !== 1) {
                    n -= firstWeekDay - 1;
                }

                //Code to fix date issue
                if(n==2)
                    n = -5;

                scope.dateValue = date.format('MMMM YYYY');
                scope.days = [];

                for (var i = n; i <= lastDayOfMonth; i += 1) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        scope.days.push({day: i, month: month + 1, year: year, enabled: true});
                    } else {
                        scope.days.push({day: null, month: null, year: null, enabled: false});
                    }
                }
            };

            var generateDayNames = function () {
                var date = scope.firstWeekDaySunday === true ?  moment('2015-06-07') : moment('2015-06-01');
                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i += 1) {
                    scope.dayNames.push(date.format('ddd'));
                    date.add('1', 'd');
                }
            };

            generateDayNames();

            scope.showCalendar = function () {
                scope.calendarOpened = true;
                generateCalendar(date);
            };

            scope.closeCalendar = function () {
                scope.calendarOpened = false;
            };

            scope.prevYear = function () {
                date.subtract(1, 'Y');
                generateCalendar(date);
            };

            scope.prevMonth = function () {
                date.subtract(1, 'M');
                generateCalendar(date);
            };

            scope.nextMonth = function () {
                date.add(1, 'M');
                generateCalendar(date);
            };

            scope.nextYear = function () {
                date.add(1, 'Y');
                generateCalendar(date);
            };

            scope.selectDate = function (event, date) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selectedDate = moment(date.day + '.' + date.month + '.' + date.year, 'DD.MM.YYYY');
                ngModel.$setViewValue(selectedDate.format(scope.format));
                scope.viewValue = selectedDate.format(scope.viewFormat);
                scope.closeCalendar();
            };

            // if clicked outside of calendar
            //var classList = ['my-datepicker', 'my-datepicker-input'];
            var classList = [];
            classList.push(scope.dynamicMyDatePicker);
            classList.push(scope.dynamicMyDatePickerInput);
            if (attrs.id !== undefined) classList.push(attrs.id);
            $document.on('click', function (e) {
                if (!scope.calendarOpened) return;

                var i = 0,
                    element;

                if (!e.target) return;

                for (element = e.target; element; element = element.parentNode) {
                    var id = element.id;
                    var classNames = element.className;

                    if (id !== undefined) {
                        for (i = 0; i < classList.length; i += 1) {
                            if (id.indexOf(classList[i]) > -1 || classNames.indexOf(classList[i]) > -1) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                scope.closeCalendar();
                scope.$apply();
            });

        },
        template: 
        '<div><input type="text" ng-focus="showCalendar()" ng-value="viewValue" class="my-datepicker-input" ng-class="dynamicMyDatePickerInput" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"></div>' +
        '<div class="my-datepicker" ng-class="dynamicMyDatePicker" ng-show="calendarOpened">' +
        '  <div class="controls">' +
        '    <div class="left">' +
        '      <i class="fa fa-backward prev-year-btn" ng-click="prevYear()"></i>' +
        '      <i class="fa fa-angle-left prev-month-btn" ng-click="prevMonth()"></i>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <span class="date" ng-bind="dateValue"></span>' +
        '    <div class="right">' + 
        '      <i class="fa fa-angle-right next-month-btn" ng-click="nextMonth()"></i>' +
        '      <i class="fa fa-forward next-year-btn" ng-click="nextYear()"></i>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '  <div class="day-names">' +
        '    <span ng-repeat="dn in dayNames">' +
        '      <span>{{ dn }}</span>' +
        '    </span>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '  <div class="calendar">' +
        '    <span ng-repeat="d in days">' +
        '      <span class="day" ng-click="selectDate($event, d)" ng-class="{disabled: !d.enabled}">{{ d.day }}</span>' +
        '    </span>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</div>'
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mousedown` event to close the calendar:

```
$document.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    scope.closeCalendar();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

Additionally you would have to stop the propagation of the `mousedown` event triggered on the calendar itself so it doesn't close itself when you select a date:

```
<div class="my-datepicker" ng-show="calendarOpened" ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

To be able to put the selected date into the `input`, have the following code in `selectDate()` method:

```
scope.val = selectedDate.format(scope.format);
```

and bind the `val` variable to the `input` element:

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="showCalendar()" ng-model="val" .../>
```

Here the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H5FgO0tcuBHN2S4WMUJW?p=preview).

Comment: with this code you are not able to select a date from datepicker

Comment: @Nesh , I changed the `selectDate` method and `input` binding in template. See the updated answer and updated plunker.

Answer (score 0):

The way I think you should go forward with this is to implement a `myDatepickerService` which handles all of the logic of hiding/showing and keeping only a datepicker.

Here's some "pseudocode" to get your mind started:

```
myApp.service('myDatepickerService', function () {
  this.datepickers = [];
  this.currentDatepicker = null;

  this.openDatepicker = function($scope) {
    if (this.currentDatepicker) {
      this.closeDatepicker();
    }

    this.currentDatepicker = $scope;
    $scope.showCalendar(); // From your linking function
  };

  this.closeDatepicker = function () {
    this.currentDatepicker.closeCalendar();
    this.currentDatepicker = null;
  };
});
```

Then on your directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDatepicker', ['myDatepickerService', function(myDatepickerService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        checkval: "="
    },
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      $scope.open = function () {
        myDatepickerService.openDatepicker($scope);        
      };

      el.on('click', $scope.open);
    }
  };
});
```

EDIT: Adding more into why I think this is the good way to go.

So, IMHO you're putting a lot of responsibility on each datepicker and it's also not efficient, since all the code that listens for the click on the `$document` is run everytime that a new datepicker is created and, what's even worst is that everytime a click reaches the `$document` it will run on **every** single datepicker. In this way, you're separating this code from every element and making it go to the Service.

Also, for what is worth, I think you should put the logic into the controller instead of the linking function but that's another story!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I will try the service way, though my initial thought is to add a dynamic class to each calendar and calendar input (`dynamicMyDatePicker` & `dynamicMyDatePickerInput`) and show/hide calendar on clicked input element basis.

Comment: I am checking the click everytime so that I know where was the click in the input or calendar itself to remain activated

Comment: Yes but that handler is run on every single click on every single datepicker which is really unperformant. You should be binding to the element and the "datepicker's" elements not the $document.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to solve this problem:

1. Put a document `'click'` handler inside the directive `link()` function, to check if the click was done inside the current directive element or not.
   This is basically your solution, although it can be improved by using jQuery $.closest() method: https://api.jquery.com/closest/
2. Use a more structured approach, and aggregate the list of calendar directives under another directive, that is responsible for synchronizing the `calendarOpened` flag for all of them.
   Such a directive would listen to the array of `calendarOpened` values for all the calendar directives, and make sure only one of them stays true after there is a change (a calendar is opened/closed)

Comment: my `click` is inside `link` - `$document.on('click', function (e) { .. })`